# How can i pass | as text from Ansible inventory to Helm values.yml

Tags: ansible, yaml, kubernetes-helm, grafana

I would like to add custom annotations to my grafana ingress, Im using Ansible and Helm to deploy the ingress.
The Helm Values are:

```
grafana:
  ingress:
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
        http2_max_header_size 16k;
        http2_max_field_size 16k;
    enabled: true
    hosts:
    - grafana.XXXX
```

The problem is creating this Value file using Ansible.
I'm unable to pass the raw snippet as it is. The outcome I'm getting is:

```
grafana:
    ingress:
        annotations:
            nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: 'http2_max_header_size 16k;

                http2_max_field_size 16k;

                '
        enabled: true
        hosts:
        - grafana.XXXXX
```

(to create the file I'm using to_nice_yaml format)

Any idea how can i pass those variables as is?

Answer (score 0):

Those two forms are equivalent, as a round-trip through `from_yaml | to_yaml` or even `to_json` would demonstrate:

```json
{
...
    "annotations": {
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet": "http2_max_header_size 16k;\nhttp2_max_field_size 16k;\n"
    },
...
}
```

[The fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) claims, correctly, that `| to_yaml` honors [all the flags from PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#the-yaml-package) as one can see:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ awesome | to_yaml(default_style="|") }}
  vars:
    awesome:
      has_newlines: "this is awesome;\nso is this;\n"
```

gets transformed into the `: |` style you desired:

```yaml
    "has_newlines": |
      this is awesome;
      so is this;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer:) 
I cant use this because i have more annotations which i don't wanna change their default style.
I also don't want to change it to json- all of my other charts are in yaml 
Do you know any other way?

Comment: There is mention in the PyYAML docs of a custom formatter class, but honestly, you are fighting an uphill battle trying to create vanity outputs for a _machine readable_ file. The computer doesn't care, so one should carefully consider whether using ansible for whatever it is you're doing with that file is solving the right problem